# Convert a byte to a string in Go

Tags: arrays, string, go, byte

I am trying to do something like this:

```
bytes := [4]byte{1,2,3,4}
str := convert(bytes)

//str == "1,2,3,4"
```

I searched a lot and really have no idea how to do this.

I know this will not work:

```
str = string(bytes[:])
```

Comment: http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not the most efficient way to implement it, but you can simply write:

```
func convert( b []byte ) string {
    s := make([]string,len(b))
    for i := range b {
        s[i] = strconv.Itoa(int(b[i]))
    }
    return strings.Join(s,",")
}
```

to be called by:

```
bytes := [4]byte{1,2,3,4}
str := convert(bytes[:])
```

Answer (score 12):

Similar to inf's suggestion but allowing for commas:

`fmt.Sprintf("%d,%d,%d,%d", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3])`

Answer (score 7):

If you are not bound to the exact representation then you can use `fmt.Sprint`:

```
fmt.Sprint(bytes) // [1 2 3 4]
```

On the other side if you want your exact comma style then you have to build it yourself using a loop together with `strconv.Itoa`.

Answer (score 3):

using `strings.Builder` would be the most efficient way to do the same..

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func convert( bytes []byte) string {
    var str strings.Builder
    for _, b := range bytes {
       fmt.Fprintf(&str, "%d,", int(b))
    }
    return str.String()[:str.Len() - 1]
}

func main(){
    s := [4]byte{1,2,3,4}
    fmt.Println(convert(s[:]))
}
```

=> `1,2,3,4`

Answer (score 0):

```
func convert( b []byte ) string {
    s := make([]string,len(b))
    for i := range b {
        s[i] = string(b[i])
    }
    return strings.Join(s,",")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is a bit trickier if you need to convert a null-terminated C character array (a C "string") returned by a legacy C function, to a Go string (which is what I needed to do). Since C arrays do not inherently have a length (C buffer overflows are notorious sources of security issues and bugs), you must manually find the actual 'end' of the C array by finding the location of the first 0 (null) after the C function returns:

```
bLength = 256 // should be >= the length C function expects
buffer = make([]byte, bLength) // make fixed length byte buffer to pass to C function

someCFunctionThatPutsCharactersIntoBuffer(&buffer[0]) // call the C function, passing address of first byte in buffer

lastPos int = bLength // or lastPos int = len(buffer) - assume buffer is full, possibly without null terminator
for i := range lastPos // C bug may mean buffer is NOT null terminated
    if buffer[i] == 0 {
       lastPos = i      // get true last position
       break
    }
goStringFromC = string(buffer[:lastPos]  // an empty string if lastPos is 0
```

**NOTE** that if the C function returns, say, a 32-bit float, you would need to import the **binary/encoding** and **math** packages, and after calling the C function use something like:

```
bits := binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buffer) // get first 4 bytes of buffer, assuming x86/x64 architecture
var f float32 = math.Float32frombits(bits) // convert raw bits to float32
```

The same approach works for other numeric values.

Answer (score -1):

`hex.EncodeToString(input)` may work for you.