# How to get a string's hex value with string type in Go

Tags: go

I have a string, `byteArray`:

```
byteArray := []byte("Hello, 世界-123..")
fmt.Println(byteArray)
```

which looks like:

```
[72 101 108 108 111 44 32 228 184 150 231 149 140 45 49 50 51 46 46]
```

I need to get `byteArray[0]` as a string, like `"72"`, but they're byte type.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You are looking for [strconv.Itoa](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) or [strconv.FormatUint](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint). That's not hex encoding, though.

Comment: Thank,  strconv.Itoa will work.I found an answer here, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31220421/convert-a-byte-to-string-in-golang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strconv.Itoa`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa):

```
byteArray := []byte("Hello, 世界-123..")

for _, v := range byteArray {
    s := strconv.Itoa(int(v))
    fmt.Printf("%T, %v\n", s, s)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There you go.

```
byteArray := []byte("Hello, 世界-123..")
fmt.Println(string(byteArray[0]))

// H
```

Comment: ```
string(byteArray[0] 
``` 
this will turn byte "72" to string "H"