# override string method using Stringer interface for a custom type (byte[4])

Tags: go

I am doing some tasks at the official 'A Tour of Go' page. I have defined a custom type `IPAddr` which is of type `byte[4]`.

Lets say that a value of a type `IPAddr` is `{127, 2, 0, 1}`.

I need to override the `String()` method so that it gets printed in the form `127.2.0.1` instead of `[127, 2, 0, 1]`.

Here is the code and where I am stuck:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (p IPAddr) String() string {
   return string(p[0]) + "." + string(p[1]) + "." + string(p[2]) + "." + string(p[3]) // this here does not work. 
   //Even if I simply return p[0] nothing is returned back.
}

func main() {
    a := IPAddr{127, 2, 54, 32}
    fmt.Println("a:", a)
}
```

Comment: String conversion does not convert an integer value to decimal text as assumed by the code in the question.  Use the fmt or strconv package to get decimal text.

Comment: I needed byte to String conversion

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos `byte` and `int8` are the same type. Type conversions like `typename(value)` are only used in cases where the types in question have equivalent or very similar memory representation, e.g. `string([]byte{})`, `int(byte(1))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a byte to a string in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31220421/5728991).  This question wants "," instead of "." separators, but is otherwise the same.

Comment: "I have defined a custom type IPAddr which is of type byte[4]." -- `byte[4]` is not valid Go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the string conversion the values are getting casted in a way that you are not expected. You can notice that 54 is printing as 6 since the ascii value of 54 corresponds to "6".

Here is a way to get the expected result using fmt.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type IPAddr [4]byte

func (p IPAddr) String() string {
   return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]) 
}

func main() {
    a := IPAddr{127, 2, 54, 32}
    fmt.Println("a:", a)
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem thanks. Glad to know that we must use this Sprintf for string conversions.